# Cant use ENUM in new tables

Tags: mysql, sql

After I updated my WAMP server with mysql version 5.7.14, apache version 2.4.23, and php version 7.0.10. Not sure if php version mather but its there if you need it.

After the updated I've not been able to create new tables where one or more of the column uses `ENUM`, after searching about it, I found a thread that recomended using something ells than `ENUM` but since it have been working well so far, I dont see the problem with it(?). After the update I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) NOT NULL ,
`rank` ENUM(0) NOT NULL ,
`avatar` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
`' at line 13
```

It works when removing the ENUM columns but I need them. Heres the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `az2983`.`users` ( 
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `question` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `answer` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `ip` INT(25) NOT NULL ,
    `active_ip` INT(25) NOT NULL ,
    `level` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    `exp` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    `title` ENUM(0) NOT NULL ,
    `rank` ENUM(0) NOT NULL ,
    `avatar` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `bio` VARCHAR(1800) NOT NULL ,
    `banner` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `f_post` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    `f_threads` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    `post` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    `profile_visible` ENUM(0) NOT NULL ,
    `link` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `born_date` DATE NOT NULL ,
    `active` ENUM(0) NOT NULL ,
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    `banned` ENUM(0) NOT NULL ,
    `founder` ENUM(0) NOT NULL ,
    `awards` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    `friends` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Comment: I think your syntax for `ENUM` is incorrect. As per `MySQL` docs you should create enum like this: `size ENUM('xyz', 'abc', 'pqr') NOT NULL` You can follow this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: An enumeration value must be a quoted string literal. So `\`title\` ENUM('0') NOT NULL ,` would work, although I see no earthly use in a ENUM with ONE VALUE

Comment: My magic crystal ball tells me that you forgot to mention one important information: You didn't write that query by hand, but used phpmyadmin. My magic crystal ball is even able to tell me that you are using phpmyadmin version 4.6.4. You have to correct your enums by hand (see the other comments/answers with the correct enum syntax) or downgrade your phpmyadmin version to 4.6.3 or wait for 4.6.5, because 4.6.4 has a bug that ruins types like `enum` or `decimal(10,2)`, while I am going to ask my magic crystal ball for the lottery numbers, because it seems to be on a good run right now.

Comment: When i was using phpmyadmin that when i got the error, and the code is a direct copy from preview SQL button within pphmyadmin. it apears that it doesnt recognize the input in ENUM inoutfields. the problem has been solved now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ENUM`erations wrong. You can't put in `0` because that's not an ENUM, it's an integer.

Use it like this:

```
ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: It gives me 0 when i click preview SQL, but when using phpmyadmin i use `'0', '1'`. can the problem be phpmyadmin? that it dosnt recognize the input fields for enum?

Comment: @martinj Yes, I remember times when some phpMyAdmin versions did not correctly transform ENUMs. Maybe an update resolves this!